# Error in Creating View Oracle MySQL

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
Create View ViewA AS

Select o.orderid, o.dishid, o.quantity, o.ordertime, o.deliveryaddress, d.dishid, r.description, r.location, c.firstname, c.lastname, c.phonenumber, c.address, c.city, c.state, c.zip

FROM Orders o

JOIN Dishes d On (o.dishid = d.dishid)

JOIN Customers c ON (o.customerid = c.customerid)

JOIN Restaurants r ON (d.restaurantid = r.restaurantid);
```

I am supposed to create a view like this but i do not understand the error that reads:

ORA-00957: duplicate column name
00957. 00000 -  "duplicate column name"

Where is the duplicate column name?

Answer (score 1):

You must provide aliases for every column.

Run this:

```
Create View ViewA AS Select o.orderid ORDER_ID, o.dishid ORDER_DISH_ID, o.quantity ORDER_QUANTITY, o.ordertime ORDER_TIME, o.deliveryaddress DELIVERY_ADDRESS, d.dishid DISH_ID, r.description RES_DESCRIPTION, r.location RES_LOCATION, c.firstname CUST_FIRSTNAME, c.lastname CUST_LASTNAME, c.phonenumber CUST_PHONE, c.address CUST_ADDRESS, c.city CUST_CITY, c.state CUST_STATE, c.zip CUST_ZIP FROM Orders o JOIN Dishes d On (o.dishid = d.dishid) JOIN Customers c ON (o.customerid = c.customerid) JOIN Restaurants r ON (d.restaurantid = r.restaurantid);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `o.dishid` and `d.dishid` - oracle will try to call both `dishId` - You need to alias them